# How to call a non-static member function within its own class in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, callback, boggle

I am building a class Boggle in C++. In the Boggle class, I have declared a structure type called boardIndex:

```
struct Boggle::boardIndex {
    int row, col;
};
```

And a callback function to compare two "boardIndex"s:

```
int Boggle::CmpByIndex(boardIndex a, boardIndex b)
```

I want to pass the callback function to a Set of boardIndex elements within the Boggle.cpp file:

```
Set<boardIndex> usedIndices(CmpByIndex);
```

Is this possible? In the current form, I'll get an error that a "reference to non-static member function must be called." I don't have any objects of the Boggle class - is there another way of calling the CmpByIndex function here?

Comment: Please show actual code, not your interpretation of it. What you show is not compilable at all.

Comment: Try to declare `int Boggle::CmpByIndex(boardIndex a, boardIndex b)` as a friend function

Comment: If you don't have objects of the class, all your member functions should be static.

Comment: Member functions needs an *object* to be called on. Have you tried making the function `static` (which is hinted at by the error message)?

Comment: @someprogrammerdude the **title** precisely asks how to do it *without* making a function static, so suggesting to make it `static` makes no sense

Comment: @Fureeish But it seems like his mistake is in making the function non-static in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar but should we assume that? I'm pretty sure that declaring that function as a `friend` will solve the problem **and** it won't become `static`

Comment: @Fureeish If it's not static, you need to call the method through an object. What object will it be called through?

Comment: @Fureeish Why should it be a `friend` function? Do you mean to turn the *member* function into a non-member function? Also, the title just says that the function is *currently* non-static, but I see no requirement that it must stay that way (even though it might be loosely implied).

Comment: @Barmar, if a function is declared as a friend, you can pass object as a parameter. However yes, I see my bad logic here, I pointed out the title and I also ignored the fact that `friend` makes a function non-member. My bad

Comment: @Fureeish being a friend of a class doens't allow you to pass an object of that class as a parameter, *all* functions can do that. Friendship gives you access to privates

Comment: @caleth I do know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have any objects of the Boggle class - is there another way of calling the CmpByIndex function here?

If you do not have any objects then you cannot call non-static member function. So you have 2 solutions:

- make this function either static or non member of class `Boogie`
- create or somehow obtain an instance of `Boogle` and bind it to call of this method